# preg_match expression how to ignore a character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am absolutely a newbie and have not ventured to this level yet but needed to be able to strip a domain down to only the hostname for a search function. I looked and found this below which pretty much works except if the domain name has any `-` in it. So `http://www.example.com` strips down to `example.com` as does `www.example.com` but `www.exa-mple.com` becomes `example.com`.

```
$pattern = '/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
$url = $myurl;
if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches) === 1) {

    $mydom = $matches[0];
}
```

What would have to be changed in the expression so that it accepts the `-` in the domain names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex currently allows the character `_` and disallows the character `-`, which means it accepts invalid URLs.  You can correct this with the following group:

```
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9-]+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
```

Note that there are still issues with this.  First, domain names are not allowed to start or end with a hyphen. Second, you are currently allowing any character in the TLD, whereas they only contain letters.

The best solution would be to use a proper URL parsing library and not to try to do this yourself.

Comment: For now the pattern you posted will do what I need it to do, while I study more!  Thank you lonesomeday

Answer (score 5):

You'd be better off with [`parse_url`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
parse_url($url)
```

Just prepend `http://` if the url doesn't start with it.

Comment: Hi SilentGhost thank you for your quick reply!  I will look at parse_url($url)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sites = array('mysite.com',
'www.mysite.com',
'http://www.mysite.com',
'www.my-site.com',
'sub.folder.2.example.com',
'http://www.mysite.com/argh/index.php');

$reg = '%^(?:http://)?(?:[^.]*\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)%m';

foreach($sites as $site)
{

    if(preg_match($reg,$site,$matches))
    {
        echo $matches[1],PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
mysite.com
mysite.com
mysite.com
my-site.com
examle.com
mysite.com
```